# CallFunc doesn’t get called after delay

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have two functions in a node subclass that do some animating with actions.  When one is running, and the other function is called, I want to ensure it’s handled gracefully.  So I made a test:

```
Monster * node = Monster::create();
addChild(node);

auto sequence1 = Sequence::create(CallFunc::create(std::bind(&Monster:: animateWalk, node)),
                                  DelayTime::create(2.0),
                                  NULL);
// wait 2 seconds, then call this function
auto sequence2 = Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(2.0),
                                  CallFunc::create(std::bind(&Monster::animateBite, node)),
                                  NULL);

auto repeat1 = RepeatForever::create(sequence1);
auto repeat2 = RepeatForever::create(sequence2);
node->runAction(repeat1);
node->runAction(repeat2);
```

The first function is called (animateWalk) but the second function (animateBite) is never called.  If I comment out the first runAction for repeat1, then the second sequence does run.  How can I run the second function after a delay while the first one is running?

Comment: Can you please show us What you are doing in `Monster::animateBite` and `Monster:: animateWalk`. Then I can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Monster * node = Monster::create();
addChild(node);

auto sequence1 = Sequence::create(CallFunc::create(std::bind(&Monster::   animateWalk, node)),
                              DelayTime::create(2.0),
                              NULL);
 // wait 2 seconds, then call this function
 auto sequence2 = Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(2.0),
                              CallFunc::create(std::bind(&Monster::animateBite, node)),
                              NULL);


// You can do something like this 

**auto FinalSeq = Sequence::create(sequence1,DelayTime::create(2.0),sequence2);

auto FinalAction = RepeatForever::create(FinalSeq);

node->runAction(FinalAction);**
```

Comment: If you put a `RepeatForever` action in sequence, next actions will never be called !

Comment: oh my bad .. yaa you are absolutely right , i just edit my answer . i think is should work

Comment: Always the little mistakes.  As I attempted to stop previous actions in one of the animate methods, it stopped all actions, preventing the code from running.  Thanks for the help and I believe your solution is much more efficient.